# Synonymize [legal-proceedings] with [laws]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I think that we should synonymize [legal-proceedings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-proceedings) with [laws](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laws). Legal proceedings has 4 questions, Laws has 31. Legal proceedings is part of laws, right? So can we please synonymize these?

Comment: I'm so very very bored of all this retagging. I've yet to see any discernible bonus or improvement to the site. All I've seen is the disfigurement of the front page for days at a time.

Comment: Pretty sure the new questions tab stays pristine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, let’s get rid of the [legal-proceedings] tag.**

The tag wiki description for [laws] reads:

> Questions relating to in-universe laws of a work.

That is an equally apt description of legal proceedings (which doesn’t have a tag wiki of its own). It’s hard to see a distinction between the tags; as such, we should move to abolish one of them. Since [legal-proceedings] has fewer questions and no description, that‘s the one to go.

Additionally, three of the four questions tagged with [legal-proceedings] are already tagged with [laws]. In its current form it isn’t adding anything useful to the questions.

Comment: My gut feeling, if a distinction were to be made (based on the tags alone, not the questions they’ve been applied to) would be that [tag:legal-proceedings] would be for something like writers/creators suing studios or vice-versa; i.e., out-of-universe legal cases that some story/franchise may have been caught up in. But I would guess there are probably so few questions that would need such a tag that that doesn’t really change the lack of need for a [tag:legal-proceedings] tag.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yeah, I should probably have said “the way the legal proceedings tag” is being used. Still, moot as the tag is gone now.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the [legal-proceedings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-proceedings) from the questions it's currently on. Three of those already have [laws](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laws) and the other one doesn't need (it may need a [copyright](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright) or somesuch).